# How to create div next to selected word from?

Tags: html

How we can create a div next to selected word from the paragraph. Let say we have a paragraph.

"Hello how are you"  if I select how then div should be created after this paragraph like

"Hello how are you" => `<div id="newDiv"></div>`

similarly

"whats going on" => `<div id="newDiv"></div>`

means how should I find that where to create a div?

Comment: I understood that you would like to have <div> inside <p> in some line. You cannot nest a <div> element inside a <p> element according to the HTML standard. Insted of <div> you can put <span>.

Comment: Ok then is there any way I can insert div after certain positions like I have start and end index of selected words can we do anything with those indexes? Because when I select any word I have its start and end index

Comment: You can take your text from paragraph like a string and in jquery use your start and end index to expand it.

Comment: @namit also you cannot have two seperate div's with the same ID they must be unique to each element, if you wish you can replace these with class..

Answer (score 0):

**I hope this will help you**

```
 <h3>Select any of the line</h3>

<hr>

<div>
    <p> <span onclick="p1()">how are you ?</span> <br>
        <span onclick="p2()">hey what's up?</span> <br>
        <span onclick="p3()">Hello , where are you?</span> <br>
    </p>
</div>

<div>  <hr>
    <h3 style="display: none;" id="s-head">You Are Selected</h3>
    <h4 id="preview"> </h4>
</div>

<script>
    function p1(){
        document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML = "how are you ?"
        document.getElementById("s-head").style = "display:block"
    }

    function p2(){
        document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML = "hey what's up?"
        document.getElementById("s-head").style = "display:block"
    }

    function p3(){
        document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML = "Hello , where are you?"
        document.getElementById("s-head").style = "display:block"
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hii Thanks for your reply. So basically if I have one paragraph which contains 5 lines if I select one word from the first-line and click on the button Add Div then one div box will create at end of that line from which word is selected.

Comment: @namit if you wish to have a paragraph that is styled so it has 5 seperate lines then you should use the <pre> html tag which stands for pre-formatted text and will retain any line breaks without the use of <br> alternatively use 5 <span> elements inside of a paragraph.

Comment: Thank you but m not getting it can you add div after it recognizes line or word ?